# java execute command prompt problem

Tags: java, command, execute, prompt

```
public class CmdExec {

     public static void main(String argv[]) {
            try {
                Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
                StreamWrapper error, output;
                String TEMP = "/output:C:\\InstallList.txt product get name,version";     
                System.out.println(TEMP);
                CmdExec rte = new CmdExec();
                Process proc = rt.exec("wmic");
                proc = rt.exec(TEMP);

                error = rte.getStreamWrapper(proc.getErrorStream(), "ERROR");
                output = rte.getStreamWrapper(proc.getInputStream(), "OUTPUT");
                int exitVal = 0;
                error.start();
                output.start();
                error.join(3000);
                output.join(3000);
                exitVal = proc.waitFor();
                System.out.println("Output: "+output.message+"\nError: "+error.message);



     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
}
```

getting Exception :

java.io.IOException: CreateProcess: \output:C:\InstallList.txt product get name,version error=123
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at CmdExec.main(CmdExec.java:20)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html), that will supposedly explain what a `StreamWrapper` is.  It would also help to ask a specific question, as Jon alluded to, even if it is only "How do I solve this exception?".

Comment: Runtime.exec starts a new Process for every invokation. exec("wmic") will start a process without arguments and exec(TEMP) has commandline arguments without an executable. The result is nonsense and fails.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to execute `"/output:C:\\InstallList.txt product get name,version"` as a command and that isn't working.  (Indeed, it looks like nonsense to me.)

I expect that you should be executing the command like this:

```
    rt.exec("wmic /output:C:\\InstallList.txt product get name,version");
```

Comment: Why not use a `String[]` for the args to `rt.exec()`?  That way such output paths as `C:\\Program Files\\InstallList.txt` can be handled without escapes or obtuse substitution characters.

Comment: @Andrew - in general, true.  In this particular case, it makes no difference.  (The "\" has to be escaped anyway ...)